# Arrange internal frames

Tags: plot, workspace, jinternalframe

In a workspace I would like to arrange vertically or horizontal two or more InternalFrames, such as the attached pictures

[image: Original Plot]

[image: Arrange Vertically]

[image: Arrange Horizontally]

What is the best solution to do this?

Thanks